# Pass parameters to web api from console application

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I need to communicate with a web api from a console application.

The api needs two variables/parameters passed to it like so:

```
    [HttpPost("api/loans/range/enroll/{loanStart}/{loanEnd}")]
    public IActionResult PostLoanData(DateTime loanStart, DateTime loanEnd)
    {
        Loans.CreateLoanDates(loanStart, loanEnd);
        return NoContent();
    }
```

So in my main method, I did something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var LoanDateRange = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {"loanStart", startDate.ToString()},
                    {"loanEnd", endDate.ToString()}
                };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LoanDateRange);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.PostAsync("http://mybank1.com/api/loans/range/enroll", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            .ContinueWith(task => {
                var response = task.Result;
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                });
        Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

When I run the program I just get a null exception.

How can I give the api what it needs from a console application?  Or maybe, can I change the api so that it can better interact with the console app?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your startDate/endDate initialized???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

Create a model

```
class DateModel 
{
    public DateTime LoadStart {get;set;}
    public DateTime LoadEnd {get;set;}
}
```

then update your api

```
[HttpPost("api/loans/range/enroll")]
public IActionResult PostLoanData([FromBody] DateModel loan)
{
    Loans.CreateLoanDates(loan.LoadStart, loan.LoadEnd);
    return NoContent();
}
```

then call from console app

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var LoanDateRange = new DateModel();
        LoanDateRange.LoadStart = startDate.ToString();
        LoanDateRange.LoadEnd = endDate.ToString();

    UploadAsync(LoanDateRange);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static  async Task UploadAsync(DateModel LoanDateRange)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://mybank1.com/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LoanDateRange), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                try
                {
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/loans/range/enroll", content);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // ignored
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you can't await in Main method ;)

Comment: And you need to use `[FromBody]` attribute, when you pass a model in the request body as json

Answer (score 1):

And the final version with Newtonsoft.Json

```
public class TestClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Server { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public List<ShareData> Shares { get; set; }
}

 using (var client = new HttpClient()
 {
      string uri = new Uri("http://myapiendpoint/").ToString();

      string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TestClass);
      var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
 }
```